# Who is Filip referring to as the person he hates most and more than James Holden?

Tags: character-identification, the-expanse-novels

In Babylon's Ashes Chapter 2: after Filip learns that his mother Naomi is still alive he wakes up later after a nightmare and is certain that

> there was someone he hated more than James Holden.

For the whole book I am wondering who is he referring to?
It cannot be his father while I suspected it for withholding the information it does not sit right given their good standing in the following chapters, Fred Johnson who is (iirc) mentioned at the 2nd place, the person who told him the information doesn't feel right either.
Could he mean Naomi herself, e.g. for not reaching out, however I also remember no strong indication for that?

Who is Filip referring to as the person he hates the most?

Comment: I'll just say that in the TV show, Filip has the worst mommy issues since the Emperor Nero.

Comment: Naomi, for not reaching out.

Comment: Agree - he found out she was alive in humiliating circumstances- so he hates her

Answer (score 1):

At this point in Filip's young life I'd say his hate is directed at his mother Naomi for abandoning him AGAIN. His attempts to shrug her off as irrelevant have decayed into full on hate. I've got a lot more to say on the issue (read the entire series twice as well as shorts of Memory's legion. Spoiler: he grows up and gets over it.